# HKHealthStore deleteObject and HKCorrelations

Tags: ios, ios8, healthkit

I'm having difficulty properly deleting an HKCorrelation object.  If I delete it, I end up with separate entries for each entity, and also the original correlations.  Additionally, trying to clean up each sample manually also fails.  I'm doing nothing fancy. . .just calling: HKHealthStore deleteObject.

Anyone have a working example for this?

Answer (score 3):

Deleting a correlation is not expected to delete the member objects of the correlation.  Each object should be deleted individually.  If attempting to delete the member objects is not succeeding, make sure you are not encountering an error.  The app may not be authorized to delete objects of that type, for instance.